# Why does `lsof` list the open IPv6 network file (socket) when given the `-i4` option, but not when given the `-i6` option?

Tags: debian, networking, lsof

I have an open IPv6 network file (socket) that I want to inspect using `lsof`.

What bugs me is that `lsof` reports the socket's type as IPv6, but it only shows it using `-i4` option, not the `-i6` option:

```
$ lsof -i4tcp:5000 -nP
COMMAND   PID    USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
com.docke 889 nlykkei   15u  IPv6 0xaa6d8d4d1618cbdd      0t0  TCP *:5000 (LISTEN)
$ lsof -i6tcp:5000 -nP
<no-result>
```

The `-i4` and `-i6` options filter sockets on IPv4 and IPv6 respectively? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can your update your question with the output of `lsof -v`?